# Laravel filter from colums or to foreign key

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a `subscriptions` table with a `user_id`, `date_from`, `date_to`, `plan`, `status` columns. In the blade file, there is just a single filter textbox. I want to filter based on those columns or based by `fname`, `mname`, `lname` fields from the users table. How to correctly do that in eloquent? Here is my code so far.

```php
$subscriptions = Subscription::where(function ($query) use ($q) {
    $query->orWhere('plan', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
        ->orWhere('date_from', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
        ->orWhere('date_to', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
        ->orWhere('status', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%');
})->orWhereHas('user', function ($query2) use ($q) {
    $query2->orWhere('fname', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%');
    $query2->orWhere('mname', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%');
    $query2->orWhere('lname', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%');
})->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->paginate(10)->appends('q', $q);
```

Comment: Do you have an error in your  output?
I can say juste one thing replace the first `$query->orWhere` inside the 2 Closures by `$query->where`

Comment: There was no error. I can filter correctly if i type values that is found in the subscriptions table. But if I type a name from the users table, there is not data displayed. I need the `orwhere` since I need it to compare to all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$subscriptions = Subscription::where(function ($query) use ($q) {
    $query->where('plan', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->orWhere('date_from', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->orWhere('date_to', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->orWhere('status', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%');
})->orWhereHas('user', function ($query2) use ($q) {
    $query2->where('fname', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
           ->orWhere('mname', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
           ->orWhere('lname', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%');
})->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10)->appends('q', $q);
```

Comment: It's actually the second that works. I just need to change the `role` to `user` since it is whats on my model.

Comment: Ah yes sorry it was my example :)